# How to clear multi lines in command zone

Tags: plugin-system, filetype-c++

I'm working with vim + some plugins to code c++.

Sometimes, because of some bug or some executing sequence issue, the command zone will show me two or three lines as below:
[image]

As you can see, I got two lines in the command zone:

```
"test.cpp" 62L...
:redraw
```

How could I clear them so that I can make it into one line as normal? I've tried to execute `:redraw` but it's not working.

Comment: @klaus  Yes, I did.

Comment: Try `:redraw!` with a bang

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  it works!  Maybe make it as an answer?

Comment: @klaus   No, it doesn't help.

Comment: Yves, I'll leave B Layer the credit for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. This clears the screen then redraws it. That's also what `:redraw!`, mentioned in the comments, does but this is a lot more convenient.

The one caveat is that there can be a difference in timing between the two. Per help (i.e. the first couple entries in `:h various-commands`), `ctrl-l` may delay the redraw so Vim can process typeahead input while `:redraw!` redraws right away. I've not encountered this difference myself and your scenario doesn't seem applicable...but it should be noted. Perhaps you'll be the one that has to resort to `:redraw!`.